# Returning multiple outputs from function

Tags: python, function, return, yield

I am not sure that this is possible, but...

I am trying to write a function that will output lists of numbers so that they can be input into another function. I'm at a dead end though, as neither `return` or `yield` (used in this context) can give me what I want.

```
def ITERATOR():
    for number in range(1,3):
        for item in itertools.permutations(range(15),number):
            yield item
```

Obviously, the function breaks whenever `return` is used, and `yield` returns everything at once. What I ideally want it to output is what is printed on each line by:

```
def ITERATOR():
    for number in range(2,4):
        for item in itertools.permutations(range(15),number):
            print(item)
```

i.e:

```
(0, 1)
(0, 2)
(0, 3)
(0, 4)
(0, 5)
(0, 6)
(0, 7)
(0, 8)
(0, 9)
(0, 10)
(0, 11)
(0, 12)
(0, 13)
(0, 14)
etc...
```

Is there any way of achieving this?

Comment: Don't put `return` inside a `for` loop. It immediately breaks out of the function. Also, ALL_CAPS should really be used for global variable names, not function names: see [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions)

Comment: *"`yield` returns everything at once"* - that's exactly **not** what it does. Please clarify the specific problem; how are you trying to *use* that function?

Comment: `yield` return a generator to the values it returns, you can use this generator as you wish. you don't have to accept all values at once, just iterate over it.

Comment: I have another function that outputs when a list (or tuple) of numbers is passed to it. I would like to pass each of these (0,1),(0,2),etc... to it individually.

Now that I think about it, would it be possible to do:

for item in itertools.permutations(range(15),number):
    functionTwo(item)

?

Comment: Just some correctiony to your statements: _"neither return or 'yield' (used in this context) can give me what I want"_ - both can do what you want, but you have to understand how they work. _"yield returns everything at once"_ - it definitely does not.

Comment: @Matt do you want to return the whole block of text that is printed at once or return each line as it is generated? EDIT: phone about to die, might not read any comments for a while

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return a list, you could just do it:

```
def fct():
    return [item for item in itertools.permutations(range(15),number) for number in range(2,4)]
```

And for a generator

```
def fct():
    return (item for item in itertools.permutations(range(15),number) for number in range(2,4))
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

```
new_tuples = []
for i in range(0, 5):
    for j in range(1, 16):
        new_tuples.append((i, j))

for i in new_tuples:
    print(i)
```

**Output**

> ```
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~/python$ python3 text_seg.py 
> (0, 1)
> (0, 2)
> (0, 3)
> (0, 4)
> (0, 5)
> (0, 6)
> (0, 7)
> (0, 8)
> (0, 9)
> (0, 10)
> (0, 11)
> (0, 12)
> (0, 13)
> (0, 14)
> (0, 15)
> (1, 1)
> ```

**Comments**

Would this approach satisfy your needs? You could interchange the numbers as desired but this, will allow you to have a `list` with the `tuples` store and be able to call them to `print`.

Answer (score 0):

You can return the list through the argument of the function, and use the return of the function to indicate the number of permutations founded:

```
import itertools

permut = []

def ITERATOR(item):
    n_permuts= 0
    for number in range(2,4):
        for item in itertools.permutations(range(15),number):
            permut.append(item)
            n_permuts+= 1
    return n_permuts

print (ITERATOR(permut))
for item in permut:
    print(item)
```